# How can I find the characteristic table of a D Flip Flop?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, flipflop

There is an X ff and the question is about finding the characteristic table of its. What kind of a ff is this? I can't write the logic equition. What are the inputs ? If inputs are c and x, then I need something extra to write the logic equition?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: It is D-FF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop, you should be able to find a lot of documentation on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The outputs of flipflops are commonly denoted with Q and Q'. This is the case here. As for the truth-table: One way to do it is to have a truth table with not 2 but 3 parameters as entry - your two inputs and the previous state (in other words, Q). You thus see what Q becomes, given a certain previous Q, and the inputs C and X.
Note that with feedback, it's possible to have "undefined" states - where you get contradictions or oscillations (A becomes true and makes B false, which makes A false, which makes B true, which makes A true, Which makes B false, .....)